# Login with Facebook, age_range permission

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

In the Facebook guideline it says that there is an `age_range` field included in the public profile for anyone who installs your app.

Before login with Facebook I asked for public profile permission, but i am not getting `age_range` as a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have this with all users, or just a/some specific users?

You should first let the user login and request (just) the `public_profile` permission. After that, you will have received an access token for that user. Now, you can perform the following request with that access token:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?fields=age_range&access_token=<access_token>`

That will give you the age range of the user.

Comment: This is working, but than i should perform another request, to fetch the other informations like name,surname,email.I was hoping i can manage it with one request.
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=age_range" parameters:nil];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
            // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
        }
    }];
    }

Comment: You can; you can list multiple fields in the `fields` param, by comma-separating them .